# Trying to open an xaml file that is on a CD throws IOException on some computers and not others

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application that displays loose XAML FlowDocuments (with Frame) that are located on a CD or DVD. This has worked just fine in the past, but now all of the sudden the program is crashing on a specific computer. The very strange thing is that this computer is 100% identical to other computers that this works just fine on (their hard drives are even imaged from the same hard drive image).

Not only does my application crash, but when I simply try to view these loose xaml files with internet explorer, it also cannot display them (they display fine in IE on other computers). Clicking on the more information button in IE shows me:

System.IO.IOException: The media is write protected.

Which I'm assuming is the same exception that my application is getting, though I can't actually tell the actual exception my program is getting because putting a try-catch around the Frame.Navigate function that I'm calling to display the xaml files doesn't actually catch this exception (Bonus Question: Why is that?), the program just crashes (and I don't have VS on this computer or remoting capabilities so I can't run the debugger).

Even more strange is the exception, why would it matter if the media is write protected if all I'm trying to do is read it?

Comment: can you post the code where you read the xaml from filestream.

Comment: There is no code, the loose xaml files won't even open in IE if I just try to view it off of the CD. Within my application all I'm doing is calling the Navigate method of the Frame control with the URI of the file